# Convert JSON to CSV and maintain column order

Tags: python, json, csv

I need to convert json to csv for an inventory feed with no headers and I have no problem with the conversion but the column order is getting changed. Is there a way to maintain the column order? Here is what I have:

```
   acmeInventory = Stock.objects.filter(product__type__in=(1, 9), status=1, 
   product__acmesells=True)
   data=[]

   for item in acmeInventory:
      sku = item.product.sku
      if sku == 'PROVTi-BK':
       sku = 'VTi-BK'
      if sku == 'PROVT-BK':
       sku = 'VT-BK'
      quantity = int(item.stock)
      if quantity < 50:
       quantity = 0

      itemDict={
        'Manufacturers Item #':sku,
        'Quantity Available': str(quantity),
        'Stocking Unit of Measure': 'EA',
        'Date Available': str(today),
        'Item Description': item.product.name,

      }
     data.append(itemDict)
print(data)

keys = data[0].keys()
with open('AcmeIAV220.csv','w', newline='') as output_file:
  dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file,keys)
  dict_writer.writerows(data)

ftp = ftplib.FTP(host,user,password)
ftp.encoding = "utf-8"

with open('AcmeIAV220.csv', "rb") as file:
  ftp.storbinary("STOR AcmeIAV220.csv", file)
   ftp.dir()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of dict

Here is an example: [OrderedDict in Python (GeeksforGeeks)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordereddict-in-python/)